# Make command will not work

Tags: command-line, drivers, apt, compiling

The make command for build-essential will not work, my build essential has the newest update.

im trying to install rtl8723bs, its at driver for my laptops networkcard, but when i try to do the make command it just wount work.

sorry for my verry bad english >D
[Screenshot of me trying to do the make command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y9JK.png)

[Build-essential i up to date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7uYI.png)

Comment: Why run it with `sudo`? And it does work.

Comment: Kali is off-topic here.

Comment: Related: [What do I do after running make, to use lcd-opencv-simulator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180653/what-do-i-do-after-running-make-to-use-lcd-opencv-simulator)

Answer (score 2):

First, no need to run make as root, just `make`

Second, there is no error message. In Linux as long as the command runs without errors there may be no message.

To see if it worked, run `ls` again.

I see .bin files so it appears make worked just fine.

Now run `sudo make install`

you need sudo to install as these are system files.

When in doubt, read the README and/or MAKEFILE, the make file is plain text

EDIT - you are already root, so no need for sudo at all. Why are you running as root ?

Last it appears you are not running ubuntu ;)