# What do I do after running make, to use lcd-opencv-simulator?

Tags: compiling, c++, make, libraries, opencv

I'm new to Ubuntu and I need to run a LCD simulator our professor has given us without giving us sufficient information on how to actually use it.

The program requires OpenCV, which I believe I managed to install on my Ubuntu. Then I tried to compile it using make, the result can be seen here:

[image: screenshot of terminal showing a make command that ran one g++ command which produced no error messages nor other output]

That's as far as I got, I truly don't know what to do next because I'm new to Ubuntu. Could anyone please help me with running this program?

[This is the LCD simulator, in case it is useful.](http://poli.cs.vsb.cz/edu/apps/lab/lcd-opencv-simulator.tgz)

Comment: Welcome to AU, Could you Copy/Paste from the terminal the compilation process. Screenshots don't help much.

Comment: Related: [Make command will not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/923179/make-command-will-not-work), [How to check if a command succeeded?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29370/how-to-check-if-a-command-succeeded), [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/25961/22949), and (though this isn't usually a problem and [wasn't a problem in this case](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180653/what-do-i-do-after-running-make-to-use-lcd-opencv-simulator#comment1972089_1180655)) [Can't execute .out files, getting permission denied](https://askubuntu.com/q/44675/22949)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make` appears to have finished without any errors.

If you look at the output, you see `g++ main-lcd-opencv.cpp -o main-lcd-opencv`. This indicates that the output is `main-lcd-opencv`.

Try to run it with `./main-lcd-opencv`. If this produces a error message stating that permission is denied, you have to add the execute bit with `chmod +x main-lcd-opencv` and try `./main-lcd-opencv` again.

Comment: I tried running it with ./main-lcd-opencv and the program is working now. Thank you for your help, much appreciate it.

Comment: Regarding manually adding the executable bit: `chmod +x` on a binary that was just produced by a compiler is never useful. The compiler makes it executable if it can; if it can't, `chmod +x` run by the same user, on the same file, won't do it either. Both the compiler and `chmod +x` use the current process umask. If it's really weird and masks out executable bits, `chmod u+x` could help. In practice I've never heard of a situation where that helped either, but it's *theoretically* possible that one could arise. Note that this is different from filesystem umask problems which this won't solve.